# Redis Gem LoadError / NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, redis, ubuntu-12.04, rbenv

I keep getting a LoadError / NameError when trying to use Redis with Rails on my production server

My gemfile has `require 'redis'` and I've ran bundle install
My redis.rb initializer file is like so

```
 require 'redis'
 $redis = Redis.new(host: 'localhost', port: 6379)
```

But Unicorn is outputting a `LoadError` on the `require 'redis`' line, if I remove the line I get a `NameError` on the `Redis.new` line

Here's the `LoadError`

```
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- redis (LoadError)
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/releases/20130602154455/config/initializers/redis.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/releases/20130602154455/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from config.ru:4:in `require'
    from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:595:in `init_worker_process'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:615:in `worker_loop'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:511:in `maintain_worker_count'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:277:in `join'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
    from /home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Here's the `NameError`

```
E, [2013-06-02T12:39:03.122148 #10042] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Redis (NameError)
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/releases/20130602163706/config/initializers/redis.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/releases/20130602163706/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:4:in `require'
config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:595:in `init_worker_process'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:615:in `worker_loop'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:511:in `maintain_worker_count'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:277:in `join'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/home/anujan/apps/pentakilluniversity/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: it is apparent that redis gem is not installed properly.

Comment: I tried reinstalling it with `gem install redis` and another time with bundler.

Comment: did it report success?

Comment: No, it still gives the same errors.

Comment: I mean when you ran the command `gem install redis`. Did it succeed?

Comment: Yeah, it succeeded. It's installed and shows up when I type `gem spec redis`

Comment: so if you run `irb` and type `require 'redis'` does it work? if not, are you running the version of ruby that you installed the gem for? can you see the gem installed in the file system?

Comment: It works fine when run through `irb` and `rails c` but doesn't when using unicorn. The only ruby version I have is 1.9.3 and I see the gem in the folder.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. @Anujan I would very much appreciate a hint.

Comment: @lulezi sorry for the late response. I solved this by just reinstalling ruby / rbenv.